# as3 change from random element in array to next element

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

I have an array of skin tone hex codes. At the moment, when I click a button, it randomly gets an element from the array. I'd like it to just get the next available element and if there are no more, loop back to the 1st element. Here's what I have at the moment.

```
var skinTones:Array = ["0xebae7f","0x754c24","0xf2ca8d","0xf4d1b7","0x8b6947"];
```

And the button code:

```
menuMC.buttFace.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickFace);
        function clickFace(event:MouseEvent): void 
        {
            function getSkinTone(source, amount) {
                var i = Math.round(Math.random() * (source.length - 1)); //random seed (starting point)
                var myTone = new Array(); //the new array

                while(myTone.length < amount){
                    if (i >= source.length) i = 0;  //if the current iterator if out of bounds, reset to 0
                    myTone.push(source[i]);
                    i++;
                }
                return myTone;
            }

            var toneHex = getSkinTone(skinTones,1);
            trace(toneHex);

            TweenLite.to(faceWrapperMC.faceMC, 0.5, {colorTransform:{tint:toneHex, tintAmount:1}}); 
            TweenLite.to(faceWrapperMC.earsMC, 0.5, {colorTransform:{tint:toneHex, tintAmount:1}}); 
            TweenLite.to(faceWrapperMC.eyesMC.eyes.eyelid, 0.5, {colorTransform:{tint:toneHex, tintAmount:1}}); 

        }
```

Any help would be great. Also, if it can be simplified, please let me know. This is my 1st AS3 project.

Comment: You want the first iteration to be random and the remaining iterations sequential?

Comment: In the button code, "i" is not set to anything, but it is still referenced later at "myTone[i]".  Is there some code missing?

Comment: I have removed that now thanks Gigggas. It's still bringing back random hex codes with a lot of repeats. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will take the passed array, and return a new array with a random seed (starting element) and keep the rest of the order the same.   I renamed the parameters to better clarify what I interpreted them to be.

```
    function getSkinTone(source:Array,amount:int):Array {
        var i:int = Math.round(Math.random() * (source.length - 1)); //random seed (starting point)
        var myTone:Array = new Array(); //the new array

        while(myTone.length < amount){
            if (i >= source.length) i = 0;  //if the current iterator if out of bounds, reset to 0
            myTone.push(source[i]);
            i++;
        }
        return myTone;
    }
```

**EDIT**
After some comments, I believe this is what you'd like to do:

```
var skinTones:Array = ["0xebae7f","0x754c24","0xf2ca8d","0xf4d1b7","0x8b6947"]; //these can be stored as uint instead of strings since TweenLite will just convert them to uint anyway
var skinToneIndex:int = -1; //a global var to hold the current index - starting as -1 to indicate it hasn't been set yet.

function getNextSkinTone():String {
    if(skinToneIndex == -1) skinToneIndex = Math.round(Math.random() * (skinTones.length - 1)); //if not set, make it a random starting number

    skinToneIndex++; //increment it
    if(skinToneIndex >= skinTones.length) skinToneIndex = 0; //if out of bounds reset to 0;

    return skinTones[skinToneIndex];
}

menuMC.buttFace.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickFace);
function clickFace(event:MouseEvent): void {

        var toneHex:uint = getNextSkinTone();
        trace(toneHex);

        TweenLite.to(faceWrapperMC.faceMC, 0.5, {colorTransform:{tint:toneHex, tintAmount:1}}); 
        TweenLite.to(faceWrapperMC.earsMC, 0.5, {colorTransform:{tint:toneHex, tintAmount:1}}); 
        TweenLite.to(faceWrapperMC.eyesMC.eyes.eyelid, 0.5, {colorTransform:{tint:toneHex, tintAmount:1}}); 

    }
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work... Each time I click the button, the hex still seems to be random and I'm getting a lot of repeats... Here's the trace output

0x8b6947
0x8b6947
0x8b6947
0xf2ca8d
0x754c24
0x754c24
0xebae7f
0x754c24
0xf2ca8d
0xf2ca8d
0xf4d1b7
0xf2ca8d
0xf2ca8d
0x754c24
0xf4d1b7
0x754c24
0x754c24
0xf2ca8d
0xf2ca8d
0xf4d1b7
0x754c24

Comment: It does work (I've tested it), you're issue must lie elsewhere.  On your button click event that is posted, you're only asking for one result?  Post the full code you're actually using and I can help further. If you want to see my method in action, I made a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9wEhN/1/  (Javascript and AS3 work exactly the same in this instance)

Comment: Hi. Yes, I simply want to have an array of hexs, and each time the button is clicked, it outputs next one (single) and then loops back to the first if it gets to the end. It doesn't seem to give me enough characters to insert my button code.

Comment: I've edited the code that I'm using in the orig post.

Comment: I think I understand now, you only want to randomize one time at load and then after that always give you the next tone?

Comment: Hi. I'm not even worried about the random to be honest. I don't mind it starting with the 1st element in the array and cycling through on each click so 0... 1... 2... 3... 4.... then back to 0... 1.. etc etc

Comment: Thanks for your help LDMediaServices. Really appreciate it. Should that code be in the button function or outside it? And how would I get the hex into the tweenlite lines?

Comment: Hi - Sorry for needing so much help on this! OK - I've input the code just as you have it and when I publish I don't get any errors, but instead of the hex, I seem to be getting strange traces of the toneHex each time I click. I think it might be to do with the array format change?

16044471
9136455
0
0
0
0

Comment: It's tracing out the uint equivalent of the hex value (normal behavior). For instance, if you were to do `trace(0xebae7f)`, you will get a uint number and not a hex.  It wonn't affect your program though as they are just two different ways of storing the same thing.  If you needed to display the value in hex, you could go back to storing it as a string - just change `:uint` to `:String` and wrap the hex values in quotes again.

Comment: I found a typo 'legnth' in the if statement which was cuasing it not to loop back and the 0s. I've changed it to String and Hazah!! It works!! Thank you so much for your help!